# PHP template engine - single class

Tags: php, templates, template-engine

I need very basic template engine, which is incapsulated in single class. So I would be able to easily inherit my classes from it.

All needed functionality is "for" loops, if/else, and variables placement. Even including another templates is not required.

It also must support caching for performance.

All widely-known template engines are large and not contained in single class.
And there is way too many small template engines to quickly find what I am searching for.

Comment: See [The Smallest](https://code.google.com/p/smallest-template-system/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked into all engines given in answers. Templum was closest one, but not really the  one I've looked for.

After some more searching I have found RainTPL, exactly the thing I have asked for.

Sadly, I will have to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the project [Div PHP Template Engine](http://www.divengine.com/), and i recomende to you download the last version.

Comment: Just tested this for simple output creation, only one class to include, very simple syntax, you can even use a simple echo + template + varlist and get your template running.

Comment: The license of the Div Engine is GPL. Might not be useful for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single class, it's 2 (plus a couple of exceptions) but it's the most compact and simplest template engine I've seen: http://templum.electricmonk.nl/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TinyButStrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/) am sure it has what you want.

Quoting their docs:

> Because there is only one file to install. It's made of only one class with 6 methods and 5 properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try Text-Template. It's one single class, pure regular-expressions, without the need for filesystem access; it supports loops, conditions and filters: http://github.com/dermatthes/text-template

And it will report parsing-errors with correct line-numbers :-)

Demo-Template:

```
Hello {= user.name},
{for curOrder in orders}
Order {= @index1}: {curOrder.title}
{/for}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try StampTE, it's not only a one-class template engine, it's also quite elegant because it offers 100% HTML-PHP separation. You only use HTML comments to define regions, these are called markers. No conditions, no loops, no sections.

http://stampte.com/